# How to access OSGi bundle information remotely

Tags: java, osgi, remote-access

I need to access information about all bundles and services of a remote AEM application (Apache Felix). 
Information needed for bundles:

1. Exported packages and version
2. Imported packages and version
3. Bundle status

Information needed for service:

1. Implemented interface
2. Ranking
3. path, resourceTypes, selectors for Servlets

How could we possibly gather all the above information via a Java program?

> I cannot deploy any custom remote Service on the OSGi container. Have to gather all the details, only via a Remote Java program executed externally.

Comment: Which OSGi container do you use? Also, check the API of the OSGi container how to get a list of installed bundles. Edit your question to include a description what you actually want to do, as it sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You want to look inside the remote OSGi framework but you are not allowed to install any bundles into it? I don't think it's possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 137 of the OSGi Compendium defines the OSGi REST Management Service. This provides all of the information that you're asking for using standard DTOs in a simple REST model.

The URI `framework/bundles` will list bundles which can be introspected using `framework/bundle/{bundleid}`, and `framework/services` will list services which can be introspected using `framework/service/{serviceid}`

As requested, this solution does not make use of remote services, but as mentioned in one of the comments there is no way to introspect a remote OSGi framework without installing something. In this case you must add a REST Management Service implementation to the remote framework.